# Javascript: Increase counter on click but only once every second

Tags: javascript, counter

I want to increase a counter variable every time a button is clicked but only once every second.

I have figured out to increase the counter but it increases multiple times if i click the button more than once in 1 second.

```js
var score = 0;
increaseCount() {
  score++;
}
```

how do i restrict the counter to increase by one every second?

Comment: post the logic you tried for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the function runs, set a flag that gets reset after 1 second:

```
let clickAllowed = true;
let score = 0;

function increaseCount() {
  if (!clickAllowed) {
    return;
  }
  score++;
  clickAllowed = false;
  setTimeout(() => {
    clickAllowed = true;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```js
let clickAllowed = true;
let score = 0;

function increaseCount() {
  if (!clickAllowed) {
    return;
  }
  score++;
  count.textContent = score;
  clickAllowed = false;
  setTimeout(() => {
    clickAllowed = true;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increaseCount()">click</button>
<div id="count">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var score = 0;
isClicked = false;

function incrementCount() {
  if (isClicked){
    return;
  }

  score++;
  isClicked = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    isClicked = false;
  }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow increment if a second has passed since the last click:

```js
let timeSinceLastClick;
let score = 0;

function increaseCount() {
  if (
  !timeSinceLastClick 
  || (timeSinceLastClick < Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))
  ) {
    score++;
    timeSinceLastClick = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
  }
}
```